# Angular.js setting <select> option within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the select option to a value in the ng-repeat?

The code looks like it 'should' work, but it doesn't set the select option. What am I missing?

```
<tr ng-repeat="split in splitDetails.Splits">
    <td>
        <select style="width:150px;" ng-model="splitAdjusterTo">
            <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
            <option ng-repeat="splitTo in splitDetails.PossibleAdjusters"
                    value="{{splitTo.AdjusterId}}"
                    ng-selected="{{splitTo.AdjusterId === split.ToAdjusterId}}">{{splitTo.Name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

if you want, take this json:

```
{
  "fruits": [
    {"id":1, "name" : "oranges"},
    {"id":2, "name" : "bananas"},
    {"id":3, "name" : "apples"}
  ],
  "orders": [
    {"id":1, "name" : "mark", "fruitId" : 2},
    {"id":2, "name" : "sean", "fruitId" : 1},
    {"id":3, "name" : "dave", "fruitId" : 3},
    {"id":4, "name" : "john", "fruitId" : 2}
  ]
}
```

Loop through the orders and populate selects with the fruitId... Make sense?

Comment: You really should use `ng-options`. And is there a reason it is not bound to a property of `split` as it is used inside an `ng-repeat`? If yes, then please add your JSON to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-options, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<select ng-model='split.ToAdjusterId' ng-options='splitTo.Name for splitTo in splitDetails.PossibleAdjusters track by splitTo.ToAdjusterId' ></select>
```

However, using ng-options will not allow you to insert a default option, of "--Select One--". The best way to do this, would be to ensure that the first item in the splitDetails array is equal to the following:

```
{Name:"--Select One--", ToAdjusterId: ""}
```

and ensure that within the controller split.ToAdjusterId defaults to "".

Comment: This wont work because the options are found in splitDetails.PossibleAdjusters. Imagine you have an array of fruits and an array of orders. Your looping through the orders and going to set the option of fruits based off the order fruit id.

Comment: @Mark, will it work with the edit i just pushed up (replacing "splitDetails" with "splitDetails.PossibleAdjusters")?

Comment: That does not work. That was actually the first code that I tried. It makes sense that it would work. But it doesn't...

Comment: @Mark, interesting. What sort of errors are you getting?